# Consulta MySQL - Trasnposição

Tags: mysql, sql-select, select

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT      despesa.codRequisicao,
            despesa.histDespesa,                
            despesa.despesaPassagem, despesa.despesaTaxi, despesa.despesaHotel, despesa.despesaRefeicao, despesa.despesaOutros
FROM        despesa;
```

Onde o resultado exibe desta forma:

```
1   hist1   0   200 0   0   0
1   hist2   0   0   600 0   0
```

Preciso que o resultado fique desta forma:

```
1   hist1   despesaTaxi    200
1   hist2   despesaHotel   600
```

Como faz?

Comment: Onde é que tens a informação do "despesaTaxi" e "despesaHotel"? É noutra tabela que não a despesa?

Comment: Está na mesma tabela...nestes campos (despesa.despesaPassagem, despesa.despesaTaxi, despesa.despesaHotel, despesa.despesaRefeicao, despesa.despesaOutros)

Comment: Nunca tem mais de uma despesa na mesma linha? A estrutura da tabela foi pensada para ter.

Comment: Sem dúvida, seria mais interessante repensar na estrutura, onde teria uma coluna que salvasse o tipo de despesa e uma com o valor da despesa, isso evitaria esse tipo de estrutura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta querendo unir duas colunas. O que você pode fazer, é somar as duas colunas e exibir como uma única, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT  despesa.codRequisicao,
        despesa.histDespesa,                
        (despesa.despesaPassagem + 
         despesa.despesaTaxi + 
         despesa.despesaHotel +
         despesa.despesaRefeicao + 
         despesa.despesaOutros) AS DespesasGerais 
  FROM  despesa;
```

Agora se quiser saber qual foi a despesa cadastrada na linha, você pode criar uma condição:

```
SELECT  despesa.codRequisicao,
        despesa.histDespesa,    
        IF(despesa.despesaPassagem > 0,'Passagem',
           IF(despesa.despesaTaxi > 0, 'DespesaTaxi',
              IF(despesa.despesaHotel > 0, 'DespesaHotel',
                 IF(despesa.despesaRefeicao > 0, 'DespesaRefeicao',
                    IF(despesa.despesaOutros > 0, 'DespesaOutros', 'Nenhuma Despesa')
                 )
              ) 
           )
        ) AS TipoDespesa,          
        (despesa.despesaPassagem + 
         despesa.despesaTaxi + 
         despesa.despesaHotel +
         despesa.despesaRefeicao + 
         despesa.despesaOutros) AS ValorDespesa 
  FROM  despesa;
```